# syntax error missing operator in date and time query expression

Tags: c#, winforms

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + TableName + " WHERE"
                                                + " [TIME_STAMP]=#" + TimeStamp.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm") + "#"
                                                + " AND [Slave_Id]='" + SlaveUnitID
                                                + " AND [Parameter]='" + Param
                                                + "' AND [Status]='" + Status
                                                + "' AND [Reading]='" + Reading + "'";
                                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

I am getting error in the above query.Tried but getting the same, Plz help it out

Comment: Is the error coming from C#, or from a database?  What is that database?  What is the resulting query that you're trying to execute on that database?

Comment: Do not use string concatenation to build SQL query, at least it is unsafe.

Comment: Use parameterized query instead of concatenated query string, it will prevent such hassle like this. Provide [mcve] and explain expected results in detail.

Comment: The exception is from DB i.e, OleDB

Comment: are using stored procedure ?

Comment: Check quotes : + " AND [Parameter]='" + Param should be + "' AND [Parameter]='" + Param

Comment: No use of stored procedure

Comment: Do not check quotes - use parameters to pass values to the query. Parameters will save your and our time for searching this kind of problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use parameterized query

```
conn.Open();
string query = "SELECT * FROM " + TableName + " WHERE [TIME_STAMP] =@date "
+" AND [Slave_Id]=@sid AND [Parameter] =@param  "
+" AND [Status] =@status AND [Reading] = @reading"
qlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query,conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", TimeStamp);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sid", SlaveUnitID);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", Param);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", Status);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reading", Reading );
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: can I know how these values look like `TimeStamp, SlaveUnitID, Param, Status and reading `, also want to know columns  datatype in your table

Comment: sorry,Its working fine but getting mew error Microsoft Jet DB engine cant find the Table or query.